# how add via(watpoints) points in android osm map using GraphHopper

Tags: android, openstreetmap, graphhopper

how to add multiple via(way points) in android OSM map using GraphHopper?

i am using the following code for route from A to B

```
GHRequest req = new GHRequest(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon);
GHResponse rsp = hopper.route(req);
```

here how i add another location

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
new GHRequest().addPoint(new GHPoint(lat, lon)).addPoint...
```

or

```
new GHRequest(pointList)
```

Answer (score 0):

add via point in android osm map using GraphHoppe in the following code

```
GHRequest req = new GHRequest();
req.addPoint(new GHPoint(fromLat, fromLon));
req.addPoint(new GHPoint(via1lat, via1lon));
req.addPoint(new GHPoint(via2lat, via2lon));
req.addPoint(new GHPoint(toLat, toLon));
GHResponse resp = hopper.route(req);
```

thanks Karussell